# Using ProxyPassMatch for FastCGI, results in connection refused on port 9000

Tags: mod-proxy, apache-2.4, fcgi, mod-proxy-fcgi

I'm not certain if this is a php, apache, or iptables configuration issue but I receive the following error when trying to access a `.php` file.  Please let me know if you need more information to help me diagnose, I'm at a loss for what to check next.  Thank you.

`error.log`:

```
[Thu May 08 16:43:15.392784 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 23112] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Thu May 08 16:43:15.392891 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 23112] [client 74.164.254.206:52788] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

I followed [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) and an running PHP 5.5.9 and Apache 2.4.7

I do have the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_so` modules loaded:

```
# grep LoadModule /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

Here is the ProxyPassMatch directive:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1
```

I have also tried to use UDS with the following directive, but the apache config test complains about an absolute url:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:80/path/to/root/
```

Here is `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-   unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:finger
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5   LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Check if `php-fpm` not running via **socket**. Try `netstat -tulpn | grep 9000`

Comment: Thanks @masegaloeh.  It was not running so I looked at `pool.d/www.conf` and, sure enough, it was not listening on `127.0.0.1:9000`. It's working after editing it.  If you care to phrase that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if `PHP-FPM` is running. The error log says that `apache` can't make connection to 127.0.0.1:9000. Make it running and (maybe) the error will go.

Also check if `PHP-FPM` running via socket. Maybe it's running but not listening in TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Thanks - `php-fpm` was set to listen to the `.sock` so modifying the `pool.d/www.conf` file to have `listen=127.0.0.1:9000` solved it.

Comment: `service rh-php71-php-fpm restart` fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

Per Chris's comment, I just wanted to add if apache/php does support socket connections (looks like if apache > 2.4.10, it can support it), you can also change to use that in your apache config.
I checked the php vi /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file to see what socket listening to in the listen line:

```
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

Then added that to my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file (or whatever website you want to enable on)...

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php?-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

    # Else we can just use a tcp socket:
    # SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"

    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

Then restart the web server and then index.php shows up for me:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```